# Shortcode parameter not working in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, api, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I am trying to pass amount parameters in url from the shortcode. The from and to attributes are working fine but the amount attribute is not working. The output shows the value of 1.

using the shortcode like this:

[exchange_rate from="USD" to="EUR" amount="100"]

```
function exchange_rate_shortcode($atts) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
        'from' => 'AED',
        'to' => 'NPR',
        'amount' => '1',
    ), $atts);

    $url = "https://api.fastforex.io/convert?from=" . $atts['from'] . "&to=" . $atts['to'] . "&amount=" . $atts['amount'] . "&api_key=xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx";

    $result = file_get_contents($url);
    $result = json_decode($result, true);
    return number_format((float)$result['result']['rate'], 2, '.', '') . " " . $atts['to'];
}

add_shortcode('exchange_rate', 'exchange_rate_shortcode');
```

Comment: Does the `amount` need to be passed as an interger and not quote escaped? So in your $atts `'amount' => 1` and then in your URL, `&amount= . $atts['amount'] . ` EDIT: Yeah, looking at their documentation, you don't need to wrap quotes around the `from=`, `to=` or the `amount` - look at what the URL is expecting here: https://fastforex.readme.io/reference/get_convert

Comment: thank you for responding. Can you please make changes to the code above. I am a  bit confused . I tried it but couldn't solve

Comment: @disinfor _"you don't need to wrap quotes around the from=, to= or the amount"_ - there are no "wrapping quotes" here, the `"` in the `$url = ...` assignment are the PHP string delimiters.

Comment: Rather than assembling the query string manually, you should rather use `http_build_query`. But that's probably not the root of your problem here. Can you make a debug output of `$atts`, to see what values your shortcode function actually receives?

Comment: @CBroe - ahh...I just looked at the whole string. I wrap everything in single quotes and my brain just defaulted to seeing this `"' . var . '"` Agree with the testing of the `$atts` though.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you somehow wrote the word "amount" wrong and therefore an error occurs. To avoid confusion, use the `build_query` function.

Your code will look like this:htt

```
function exchange_rate_shortcode($atts)
{
    $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
        'from'    => 'AED',
        'to'      => 'NPR',
        'amount'  => '1',
        'api_key' => 'xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx',
    ), $atts);

    // to make sure the correct value type is specified
    $atts['amount'] = (float)$atts['amount'];
    $url            = "https://api.fastforex.io/convert?" . build_query($atts);
    $result = file_get_contents($url);
    if ( ! empty($result)) {
        $result = json_decode($result, true);

        return number_format((float)$result['result']['rate'], 2, '.', '') . " " . $atts['to'];
    }

    return '';
}

add_shortcode('exchange_rate', 'exchange_rate_shortcode');
```

Comment: I think the code is not functioning

Comment: I tested it right now and it works in part of getting values from shortcode atts. I havn't api_key, but syntax's looks ok. Could you say what exactly doesn't work?